# Python: lxml installation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I want to install `lxml` in my `python34`.
But i am unable to install because of this error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() >= str()
```

What should I do?

Comment: I suppose that depends... What process were you following to get yourself into this conundrum?  e.g. are you using `pip`, `setuptools`?  Something else?

Comment: I am using pip, command was "pip install lxml"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, download the [<strike>binary installer</strike> wheel package](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and then install that directly.

Comment: I am using 64bit, windows8

Comment: It is just like that `pip install flan-flan.whl`; make sure you have updated pip first; you can do that with `pip install --upgrade pip`